# How do I parse a robots.txt file with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping, web-crawler, robots.txt

I am trying to parse a websites robots.txt file (Where facebook is will be a random url).

I want to get rid of any lines that are not for the user agent (Such as the first two in this case). So maybe get rid of any line not starting with A, D, or U?

I also want to make each user agent their own associtative array with the title being the user agent ie to get all the google bots allowed and disallows url I will print_r on $arr[googleBot].

Here is my code so far!

```
<?php 

//URl to start crawling
$start = "https://www.facebook.com";

//Url to crawl, crawled or not crawl
$crawling = array();
$crawled = array();
$disallow = array();

function getRobots($url)
{
    $robotsUrl = $url . "/robots.txt";
    ini_set("user_agent","Agent (https://www.useragent.com)");
    $robots = @file_get_contents($robotsUrl);
    $robots = explode("\n", $robots);

    $robots = preg_grep('/[^\s]/', $robots);

    print_r($robots);

}

$result = getRobots($start);
```

Comment: What is that you are stuck on, then?

Answer (score 2):

Try incorporating this with your code:

```
    <?php
function getRobots($url)
    {
        $robotsUrl = $url . "/robots.txt";
          $robot = null;
          //create an object
          $allRobots = [];
          $fh = fopen($robotsUrl,'r');
          while (($line = fgets($fh)) != false) {
            echo $line . "<br>";
           if (preg_match("/user-agent.*/i", $line) ){
                if($robot != null){
                  array_push($allRobots, $robot);
                }

                $robot = new stdClass();
                $robot->userAgent = [];
                $robot->userAgent = explode(':', $line, 2)[1];
                $robot->disAllow = [];
                $robot->allow = [];


              }
            if (preg_match("/disallow.*/i", $line)){
              array_push($robot->disAllow, explode(':', $line, 2)[1]);
            }
            else if (preg_match("/^allow.*/i", $line)){
              array_push($robot->allow, explode(':', $line, 2)[1]);
           }


          }

          var_dump($line);

          if($robot != null){
            array_push($allRobots, $robot);
          }


          //Lazy way of outputting. Loop through for prettier output.
          var_dump($allRobots);
    }

getRobots("https://www.google.com");

?>
```

Essentially, you need to loop through line by line.

- If `User-Agent` is found, create a new robot instance.
- If `disallow` is found add disallow string to robot instance
- If `allow` is found add allow string to robot instance
- If `User-Agent` found. Add robot to all robots. Start over with blank robot

Comment: Did you run that code yourself? When I tried, I got lots of errors that I could't fix.

Comment: @JamesMessingham I am sorry, i copied over wrong version. updated my answer, should compile at least.

Comment: @JamesMessingham ahh i found the issue you might be having. I was using `"split` which has been deprecated for a little while.  Changed to `explode` Try again. this should work flawlessly.

Comment: @JamesMessingham Note i used "Google" instead of "Facebook" because facebook was telling me i need to update my browser or something when i ran it on my localhost using MAMP